# Unable to connect to local LDAP server in php script

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, ubuntu, php, ldap

I have setup an LDAP server using Apache Directory Studio on my Windows 10 machine. I used all of the default settings and haven't configured anything. The address is 0.0.0.0 and the port is 10389.

I am running a php script on an Ubuntu machine on the same network that is trying to connect to this server. Running ldap_connect() and ldap_bind() fails.

It is my understanding that using 0.0.0.0 address allows you to connect to the server through the ip address of the computer it is hosted on. I am passing in "ldap://:10389", I have also tried just the ip address without the prefix and port.

I verified I can connect to a remote LDAP server and using telnet off my Ubuntu machine I can successfully connect as well.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? I am very new to this.

Comment: first, you will need to specify the port as it's non-standard,somehow.try with just the IP:port convention (without using ldap://ip:port, but just ip:port). and what is the error message that you have ? it will tell you what is happenning

Comment: @olivierg I figured out what was happening. I had to specify the correct protocol version when connecting.

Comment: glad you sorted it out :) you should mark your thread as answered!